`git pull --rebase origin dev xxxxx.git` require autentication
I want to push some software to 'dev' branch. Software was developed to another computer with Windows and currently I have reinitialize git repository from scratch on Linux machine and want to push my job to company repository and add my patch to previous dev branch
 git init
 git branch -M dev
 git remote add origin https://github.com/<company>/<repository>.git
 git add .
 git commit -m "first commit"
 git pull --rebase origin dev git@gitserv:<company>/<repository>.git

last command don't working and I don't understanding my trouble. Firstly I have Github key what looks as SHA256:CUxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Secondary I have "Personal access tokens (classic)" what we usually setting under point "Developer setting" and what look as ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Third, I have this ~/ssh/config
  Host gitserv
      HostName git.com
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.github
      IdentitiesOnly yes 
      AddKeysToAgent yes

And, of course, I have ~/.ssh/id_rsa.github and ~/.ssh/id_rsa
All looking fine, but last command
  git pull --rebase origin dev git@gitserv:<company>/<repository>.git

don't working, ask login/password and than said
  remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.

I don't understand my mistake, what I doing wrong?

You try to push to git.com when you use "gitserv". Are you sure thats your company git server? Some times you write github, then git, then gitserv. Please get your wording/meanings right. In general, add your public ssh key to your git server and you should be ready to go. Dosnt matter if github, gitlab or what ever else.

@Marc, I have changed Host name in ~/ssh/config to  'Host github' and 'HostName github.com'. And what correct format command of rebase? I try to use many variants, my last attempt without config at all - git pull --rebase origin dev https://Alex-1347:ghp_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA@github.com//.git  . Answer is "fatal: invalid refspec"

Firstly need to check what your account see github
  ssh -T git@github.com

Than best way is generate new key pair
 ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "EMAIL-for-your-Github-login"

and only than any other operation user speak in this topic - add your key to SSH key and than
 git remote add origin git@github.com:xxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy.git
 git push --force git@github.com:xxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy.git

my current Github config
Host github
   HostName github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   IdentitiesOnly yes 
   AddKeysToAgent yes

and mistake of other answer is omit first two step what is most important step
this step can be omit only for extremely newbie and LOL user who has only one Github account. Of course, any real programmer use each account for any new project to prevent illegal tracing programmer's projects and activity.

You're being prompted for username and password because you set origin to https://github.com/company/repository.git. HTTPS connections use username and token, not SSH keys.
If you want to use SSH for pushing and pulling, then git remote set-url origin git@gitserv:company/repository will change origin to use SSH with the gitserv configuration you specified.

Ok, Jim, You are right. But why I receive ''fatal: invalid refspec"  for "git pull --rebase origin dev https://Alex-1347:ghp_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA@github.com//.git" and request for username for "git pull --rebase origin dev gitserv@gitserv:/.git" - do you have any idea?

Alex-1347:ghp_redacted@github.com/... is not a valid URL as far as Git knows, so Git interpreted it as a ref - but since there is no ref in your repo by that name, it appears as "invalid refspec". git@gitserv:company/repository is a valid URL, but because origin still points to HTTPS you'll be prompted for HTTPS credentials.

"git pull --rebase origin dev gitserv@gitserv:/" this is my first idea. For this request I receive no more than request of Login and Password and than error that Git not supported Login/Password. And no more. Dead end.

Did you read my answer?

yes, I started from this point, but received only asking of login/password

You should really read that first sentence again. Maybe do it twice.

You need to add the contents of your public SSH key file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.github.pub to https://github.com/settings/keys

Thank you,  Unfortunately I have uploaded my public key to Github, I updated question and upload screen about this

You need to set it with ssh key instead of username/password
Simply follow these steps and you will set up your SSH key in no time:

Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
ssh-keygen 

Once you have your key set in home/.ssh directory (or Users/<your user>.ssh under windows), open it and copy the content



How can I add the SSH key to the GitHub account?

Login to the GitHub account

Click on your username in github (profile image on the top right side)


Click on the SSH and PGP Keys


Click on the New SSH key


Paste your key and save


And you are all set to go :-)
Now you have to execute git pull again.

Thank you, Unfortunately I have uploaded my public key to Github, I updated question and upload screen about this

If so, try this out and then pull again git config --global --unset credential.helper

for 'git pull --rebase origin dev https://Alex-1347:ghp_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA@github.com//.git" I have unswer ''fatal: invalid refspec"

and for "git pull --rebase origin dev gitserv@gitserv:/.git" git only ask login/password from me and than failed

You can move into the discussion room

Or try to reset it at system level first: git config --system --unset credential.helper

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
